# Sublime text plugin that displays the values of a selected variable?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, developer-tools

I'm hoping to get some guidance of a Sublime Text plugin that can show me the current value of a variable.

For instance, the WebStorm IDE has a nifty feature where you are able to see value of a variable based on where you selected it in the code?

See the "Debugging, Tracing, & Testing" tab on the front page of the WebStorm site for an example: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Any idea if there is plugin that does this, or is there a native feature in Sublime Text that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used it personally, but the [`Web Inspector`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Web%20Inspector) plugin looks promising. It's essentially a JS version of XDebug (for PHP), and allows you to debug code using ST2/ST3 and Chrome. Its features include:

> - Breakpoints for project stored in user settings with absolute paths.
> - Console.
> - Debugger steps and breakpoints.
> - Stack trace.
> - You can see object properties and values in console and stack trace.

so it looks like it can do what you're looking for.

Good luck!

Comment: MattDMo, this is exactly what I'm looking for! Good stuff here, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

For PHP there is [SublimeText Xdebug](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug), which integrates with Xdebug to allow you to set breakpoints at which it will show you the current value of all variables.